# C# - OpenFileDialog too slow only first time on pressing OK

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog

I have a button which opens an OpenFileDialog. When I compile the application, run it for the first time, press the button, select file(s) and then press the accept dialog button, it waits for about a minute before adding the selected file(s) into my list box.

If I close the application, restart it and do the same thing as above, everything works fast and normal. From then on it always works fast. It's only the very first time I run it after the compilation when it's too slow.

The code extract is below. What could be wrong with the dialog? Why does it run slowly for the first time? Thank you.

```
    void ButtonAddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.openFileDialog.FileName = String.Empty;
        this.openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = this.openPath;
        if (this.openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string file in this.openFileDialog.FileNames) 
            {
                if (!File.Exists(file))
                {
                    this.ShowStatus("Error occured selecting file " + Path.GetFileName(file));
                }
                else if (!this.listBoxFiles.Items.Contains(file))
                {
                    this.listBoxFiles.Items.Insert(0, file);
                }
                else{
                    this.ShowStatus("File " + Path.GetFileName(file) + " already selected");
                }
            }
        }

        if (this.listBoxFiles.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            this.openPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.listBoxFiles.Items[0].ToString());
            this.listBoxFiles.Enabled = true;
            this.buttonClear.Enabled = true;
            this.buttonFolder.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you running the application in VS, debugging? Have you tried compiling then running the application from the release folder manually to see if the same issue exists?

Comment: It doesn't matter where I run it from, nor does it matter whether it's in a debug or release mode. I use SharpDevelop. I should add only the openfilesdialog is slow the first time, any other dialog is runnig fine.

Comment: Break into the debugger during the one minute delay and see what your thread is doing.

Comment: Raymond, how can I do that?

Comment: You probably have too many windows explorer add-ins, anti-virus, etc.  This is usually not a programming issue.

Comment: There are no errors, no output shown in the IDE. It just takes too long. Some times the form window shows 'Not Responding', but after some time it adds the files and everything's working fine.

Comment: @LarsTech, if it was the system issue, it would have happen every time. But in my case it ONLY happens during the very first run after building the project

Comment: Not necessarily.  Whatever is causing it could be caching the file list on the first opening.  Or network connections are trying to connect to their servers, etc.  Try running your app on a different computer.

Comment: @LarsTech, I'm selecting files from my C drive, I'm not using network drives. I'll try another computer.

Comment: After some further investigation, looks like it is elated to Windows. In particular, if files are selected from actual hard drive folders, it works fine and fast on my and other computers. But when files are selected from MyDocuments (which is C:\\Users\user.name\ and is actually a synchronized folder), then it takes nearly a minute first, but then works fine later. Is there anything I can do? Or it's system stuff I don't have control of?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this problem of slowness at first initialisation, my suggestion is listed below to rectify this.

For VS debugging, in Visual Studio IDE, just go to Tools>Options>Debugging. Find settings page named [Symbols]. Click it to load the page content. On the right side panel if “Microsoft Symbol Servers” checkbox is checked, just uncheck it and press “Ok” to save the settings. Now on running compiled exe, if the problem still persists then I suggest to perform some cleanup operation on your pc. Also make sure that all timely VS updates are incorporated in your VS. Let me know if this helps if not we can figure out something else.

Comment: Mukesh, I'm using a SharpDevelop

Comment: You did not mention SharpDevelop before. I am sorry I don't have much clue about Symbol settings in SharDevelop. Anyway you can always try cleanup operation on pc and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);` prior to showing the `OpenFileDialog` window. That might trigger the same caching that's occurring after you do `OpenFileDialog` the first time with your current method.